# direct a log to a specific handler, but not others, in Python logging

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have a Flask application for which I would like to write a `global_error_handler` method that takes parameters like `email_admin` and only emails the admins when this parameter is `True`.

If I wanted to use Python's built in logging functionality (instead of, for example, getting the exception information from `sys.exc_info` and formatting an email myself, what are my options for how to go about this?  What I'm really stuck on is: it doesn't seems like I can say at the time the exception is raised, please direct this to this particular logging handler, and not to another.   Do I need to write more than one logger, each with a particular handler, and have different error log destinations that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your own error handlers as outlined [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/#registering), which mentions

> Handlers can be registered for any exception class, not just HTTPException subclasses or HTTP status codes. Handlers can be registered for a specific class, or for all subclasses of a parent class.

So you have the ability to define and register your own exception classes as you desire.

As for handling errors through built in logging, I would suggest you get familiar with the [Flask docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#logging) which outlines how you can either customise handlers (for example, using `SMTPHandler`), or remove default handlers altogether.

Comment: Probably my question wasn't clear, but: I want to write a function that takes a parameter that determines which handler is invoked. This function would be called in the exception. I don't want the handler type to be determined by the exception class. But maybe you're suggesting that I could catch and reraise the exception as a custom Exception type to direct it?  That's an interesting idea, but I think it will result in messier code than just having multiple logger objects (maybe I am less stuck than I thought).  

I've seen that page in the Flask docs, but thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I see what you're saying, you should be able to create a catch-all (`@app.errorhandler(Exception)`), and send additional data to this when you raise an exception in your code via kwargs.